# Google app script: exporting active slide (google slides) as PDF

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to know how I can export the active slide on the presentation as a PDF. I was able to figure it out for google sheets but nothing for google slides.

Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. I cannot understand about `I was able to figure it out for google sheets but nothing for google slides.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? 2. About exporting PDF, where do you want to export it?

Comment: Hi! Google sheets exports the entire workbook – so i was able to get the relevant sheet by hiding others, exporting, and then unhiding them. Couldn't find a similar hack for slides. For exporting, I'd like to export to a folder within the drive using the folder's ID.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to export the current active slide on Google Slides as a PDF file to the specific folder in Google Drive using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer? In this answer, I use the following flow.

1. Retrieve the active slide.
2. Create a temporal Google Slides.
3. Copy the active slide to the temporal Google Slides.
4. Delete the initial slide in the temporal Google Slides.
5. Export the temporal Google Slides as a PDF file.
6. Delete the temporal Google Slides.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of Google Slides. And, please open a slide in the Google Slide and run this script. By this, the PDF file of the active slide is created in the folder of `destinationFolderId`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const destinationFolderId = "###";  // Please set the destination folder ID.

  // 1. Retrieve the active slide.
  const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const activeSlide = s.getSelection().getCurrentPage().asSlide();

  // 2. Create a temporal Google Slides.
  const temporalSlides = SlidesApp.create("temporalSlides");

  // 3. Copy the active slide to the temporal Google Slides.
  temporalSlides.insertSlide(0, activeSlide);

  // 4. Delete the initial slide in the temporal Google Slides.
  temporalSlides.getSlides()[1].remove();
  temporalSlides.saveAndClose();

  // 5. Export the temporal Google Slides as a PDF file.
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(temporalSlides.getId());
  DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId).createFile(file.getBlob().setName(`${s.getName()}.pdf`));

  // 6. Delete the temporal Google Slides.
  file.setTrashed(true);
}
```

#### References:

- [getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getselection)
- [insertSlide(insertionIndex, slide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#insertslideinsertionindex,-slide)
- [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveandclose)
- [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! I just replaced [const activeSlide = s.getSelection().getCurrentPage().asSlide();] with s.getSlides()[1];

Comment: @Nikhil Jain Thank you for your response.