# Google apps script: Google Slide - exporting selected slides to a new slide presentation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to figure out a way to export selected slides to a new slide presentation. After holding ctrl and selecting multiple slides in the film strip (in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOYRI.png) example it is slide 2,3,4) how would I export only those selected slides to a new deck presentation?

I found an older question on stack answered by User Tanaike ([Google app script: exporting active slide (google slides) as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584781/google-app-script-exporting-active-slide-google-slides-as-pdf)) that exports the the active slide in view and converts it to PDF, but no matter what I did to edit the script it would only copy over a single slide or return an error when I ran an edited script.  I was not able to edit the code so that it would export all the selected slides.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Copying the part of Tanaike's code I was using as reference.

```
    function myFunction() {

  // 1. Retrieve the active slide.
  const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const activeSlide = s.getSelection().getCurrentPage().asSlide();

  // 2. Create a temporal Google Slides.
  const temporalSlides = SlidesApp.create("temporalSlides");

  // 3. Copy the active slide to the temporal Google Slides.
  temporalSlides.insertSlide(0, activeSlide);

  // 4. Delete the initial slide in the temporal Google Slides.
  temporalSlides.getSlides()[1].remove();
  temporalSlides.saveAndClose();
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. From your question, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: @Tanaike ! You are a Master! This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! You have my deepest gratitude!! No need to apologize at all. I have used so many of your previous contributions to develop my still very beginner skills!

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike I have one more question. I hope i am not being too much a pest. Is there anyway I can customize title of the new deck to pull in either the slide number or text within the slide? for example instead of the new presentation behind named "TemporalSlides" it can be "TemporalSlides<+first slide's slide number from the original deck>" or "Temporal Slides <+text from within the first copied over slide>. My goal select a few slides and use your code to export out the selections, then select other slides and export those out to another deck without overwriting the first export.

Comment: I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Yes, of course I will post a new question. Sorry I am new to stack and the world of coding :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's no problem. When I found your new question, I will check your new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the slides to a new Google Slides by selecting several slides in Google Slides.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this case, at first, please select the slides from the active Google Slides. And, please run this script. By this, the selected slides are copied to the new Google Slides. The new Google Slides is created to the root folder.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve the selected slides.
  const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const pageRange = s.getSelection().getPageRange();
  if (!pageRange) return;
  const slides = pageRange.getPages();

  // 2. Create a new Google Slides.
  const newSlides = SlidesApp.create("newSlides");

  // 3. Copy the selected slides to the new Google Slides.
  slides.reverse().forEach(s => newSlides.insertSlide(0, s.asSlide(), SlidesApp.SlideLinkingMode.LINKED));

  // 4. Delete the initial slide in the new Google Slides.
  newSlides.getSlides()[slides.length].remove();
}
```

- When you selected no slides, this script is not run. Please be careful this.
- If you want to copy the selected slides to the existing Google Slides, please modify `const newSlides = SlidesApp.create("newSlides");` to `const newSlides = SlidesApp.openById("###GoogleSlidesID###");`.
- When you want to link the copied slides to the original one, please use `slides.reverse().forEach(s => newSlides.insertSlide(0, s.asSlide(), SlidesApp.SlideLinkingMode.LINKED));`.

#### References:

- [getPageRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/selection#getPageRange())
- [insertSlide(insertionIndex, slide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#insertslideinsertionindex,-slide)
- [insertSlide(insertionIndex, slide, linkingMode)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#insertslideinsertionindex,-slide,-linkingmode)